# Error Reporting? Import .sql file from PHP and show errors

Tags: php, mysql

I am building a way of importing .SQL files into a MySQL database from PHP. This is used for executing batches of queries. The issue I am having is error reporting.

```
$command = "mysql -u $dbuser --password='$dbpassword' --host='$sqlhost' $dbname < $file";
exec($command, $output);
```

This is essentially how I am importing my .sql file into my database. The issue is that I have no way of knowing if any errors occurred within the PHP script executing this command. Successful imports are entirely indistinguishable from a failure.

I have tried:

- Using PHP's sql error reporting functions.
- Adding the verbose argument to the command and examining the output. It simply returns the contents of the .sql file and that is all.
- Setting errors to a user variable within the .sql file and querying it from the PHP script.

I hope I am not forced to write the errors into a temporary table. Is there a better way?

UPDATE:
If possible, it would be very preferable if I could determine WHAT errors occurred, not simply IF one occurred.

Comment: Output of the script should be stored in `$output`.  Is it not?

Comment: See second bullet. "Adding the verbose argument to the command and examining the output. It simply returns the contents of the .sql file and that is all."

Comment: you can't use php's sql error reporting functions - you don't have a connection to the database in php.  live by a command-line import, die by it.  The best you can probably hope to achieve is capturing error messages from the exec call, either using output buffering, or a return variable.

Comment: just edited my answer to what I think will be a nice solution for you.  please take a look if you have time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using  [shell_exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php)

```
$output = shell_exec( "mysql -u $dbuser --password='$dbpassword' --host='$sqlhost' $dbname < $file" );
// parse $output here for errors
```

From the manual:

shell_exec — Execute command via shell and return the complete output as a string

Note:

This function is disabled when PHP is running in safe mode.

EDIT: Full solution:

what you need to do is grab STDERR and discard STDOUT.  Do this by adding '2>&1 1> /dev/null' to the end of your command.

```
$output = shell_exec( "mysql -u $dbuser --password='$dbpassword' --host='$sqlhost' $dbname < $file 2>&1 1> /dev/null" );
$lines = explode( PHP_EOL, $output );

$errors = array();

foreach( $lines as $line )
{
    if ( strtolower( substr( $line, 0, 5 ) ) == 'error' )
    {
        $errors[] = $line;
    }
}

if ( count( $errors ) )
{
    echo PHP_EOL . 'Errors occurred during import.';
    echo implode( PHP_EOL, $errors );
}
else
{
    echo 'No Errors' . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Tim, this pointed me in the right direction, but there are some caveats. Shell_exec is disabled on my server, but using exec() with the output variable set gave me the same effect. Exec returns output as an array already, so I didn't need the explode. Other than these gotchas, your solution gave me what I needed. Thanks.

Comment: How is this working when you redirect all output to /dev/null ?

Answer (score 2):

```
$command = "mysql -u $dbuser --password='$dbpassword' --host='$sqlhost' $dbname"
  . " < $file 2>&1";
exec($command, $output);
```

The error message you're looking for is probably printed to stderr rather than stdout.  `2>&1` causes stderr to be included in stdout, and as a result, also included in $output.

Even better, use `proc_open` instead of exec, which gives you far more control over the process, including separate stdout and stderr pipes.

Answer (score 1):

When issuing a exec, the shell will return a 0 on succes, or a number indicating a failure.

$result = exec( $command, $output );

should do the trick. Check result and handle appropiate.

Comment: Thank you. That does tell me IF an error happened. Is there a way of determining WHAT error happened?

Answer (score -1):

You have done everything but look at the PHP manual! There is an additional parameter for the exec to return a result

http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

"If the return_var argument is present along with the output argument, then the return status of the executed command will be written to this variable."

```
exec($command,$output,$result);
if ($result === 0) {
 // success
} else {
 // failure
}
```

Comment: No, I saw it. This solution provides the same thing JvdBerg suggested. I realize I didn't ask for this, specifically, but it would be handy if I knew what error happened.

Comment: Perhaps passthru? http://php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php this should give you the raw output

Comment: Passthru disabled on the server.